# Has any Philip Jose Farmer books been adapted for movies or TV?

Tags: book-adaptation

I am a big fan of Philip Jose Farmer books, has anyone heard of any of his books or short stories being adapted for movies or TV?

Answer (score 1):

Riverworld has been adapted on TV : not only in [2010](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1419950/) but also apparently in [2003](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310952/). I enjoyed the books, but I haven't watched either of these adaptations.